# I'd like to propose a new computer language -- is there an SE forum where I can do so?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-recommendation

I'm working on a new computer language I call **Robato**. So far, I only have a design document, but I'd like to put it out there and see if anyone would be interested in joining the project. What Stack Exchange site would be the best for doing so? Also, what tag(s) could I use?

Comment: There are no _fora_ at Stack Exchange. No chit chat, no discussions. Clear questions and answers only.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, there is chat.

Comment: see also: [Are job offers spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276249/839601)

Comment: My question has nothing to do with brainstorming or voting.

Answer (score 11):

That's not *quite* how Stack Exchange works. You could find a site to talk about issues you have with *design*. Or even help users of your language.

Stack Exchange by design isn't *social* - while by some fluke, it *has* communities, and *pulls them together* - it's a terrible tool for actually pulling together an external community, and it's been joked it's even [anti social by design](https://blog.codinghorror.com/building-social-software-for-the-anti-social/).

It's also a tool that works very well for small, well scoped problems - and a new language is by definition a very large problem. We do nibbles - you basically need a whole 3 tier cake.

You could in theory ask questions about *building* a community in the very quiet [community building beta](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com) and use sites like Stack Overflow or even Code Review to try to polish up and get visibility for your language...

But I think what you're *really* looking for is [GitHub](https://github.com) and a little self-promotion through places like Slashdot or Hacker News.

Comment: Yep, this can be a project one can start on your own, put it public on Github, get some contributors, ...